# POST request in namespaced resource controller going to index action instead of create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I have a namespaced controller for some admin functionality.  My create form does not work -- it ends up routing the request to the index action instead of the create action.

Why isn't the POST getting routed to the create action as it should (being RESTful)?

routes.rb:

```
  map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :events
  end
```

rake routes:

```
             admin_events GET    /admin/events                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/events"}
    formatted_admin_events GET    /admin/events.:format           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/events"}
                               POST   /admin/events                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/events"}
                               POST   /admin/events.:format           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/events"}
           new_admin_event GET    /admin/events/new               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/events"}
 formatted_new_admin_event GET    /admin/events/new.:format       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/events"}
          edit_admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id/edit          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/events"}
formatted_edit_admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id/edit.:format  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/events"}
               admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/events"}
     formatted_admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id.:format       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/events"}
                               PUT    /admin/events/:id               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/events"}
                               PUT    /admin/events/:id.:format       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/events"}
                               DELETE /admin/events/:id               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/events"}
                               DELETE /admin/events/:id.:format       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/events"}
```

app/views/admin/events/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New event</h1>

<% form_for([:admin, @event]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...
```

app/controllers/admin/event_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.find(:all)
    ...
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

And finally, a bit of a log file where you can see it is indeed POSTing:

```
Processing Admin::EventsController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2008-10-16 18:12:47) [POST]
  Session ID: ...
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"admin/events", "event"=>{"location"=>""}}
  Event Load (0.000273)   SELECT * FROM `events` 
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering admin/events/index
Completed in 0.00757 (132 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00118 (15%) | DB: 0.00027 (3%) | 200 OK [http://localhost/admin/events]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the routes was the issue.  I'm not sure exactly why, but moving it below my root routes (`map.connect ''`) solves the issue, and Rails routes the requests accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This unexplainable bug just about to blow up my brain! Thanks a lot for this question.

Comment: Just want to ask what's the difference between `map.connect ''` and `map.root`?